# Spark writing extra carriage character records when saving to CSV

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a file using pyspark. my record length is 28 ( 4 columns). But when I am saving it to a text file and check the record length. it adds extra characters at the end of every record.

```py
df2 = df2.withColumn('onecol', concat(*(df2.columns))).select('onecol')
print('after concatenation')
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)
df2.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').save('/axp/aet/gardpa/dev/testfolder/pyspark')
```

using this command to check the length of records written.

```
cat test.txt   | awk '{print length($0)}'
```

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the file or may be the output of the file.